How to query CMake cache for a Visual Studio extension?
I'm currently writing a Visual Studio (not vscode) extension for CMake projects. I need to first query the base folder of the project then query some variables in CMake's cache. But I cannot find the documentation of the related API, most pages are related to the legacy Solution projects, including this one, and cannot be applied to CMake projects. Could someone help me?
